# NPM packages in process.env

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings, npm-scripts

How are all these packages installed into `process.env`, and why don't I see `NODE_ENV` set in npm scripts?

```json
"start": "NODE_ENV=dev npm run build && npm run watch && npm run tslint"
```

[image]

My npm scripts:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build && npm run watch && npm run tslint",
    "build": "npm run build-ts",
    "serve": "nodemon dist/Server.js",
    "watch": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"TypeScript,Node\" -c \"yellow.bold,cyan.bold,green.bold\" \"npm run watch-ts\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "test": "mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register",
    "build-ts": "tsc",
    "watch-ts": "tsc -w",
    "tslint": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json",
    "debug": "npm run build && npm run watch-debug",
    "serve-debug": "nodemon --inspect dist/Server.js",
    "watch-debug": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"TypeScript,Node\" -c \"yellow.bold,cyan.bold,green.bold\" \"npm run watch-ts\" \"npm run serve-debug\""
},
```

Comment: npm install maybe?  Also what does your config file look like?

Answer (score 2):

> How all these packages got into process.env

`process.env` reflects the system enviroment varaibles. E.g. run `env`. More : https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env

> And why I don't see NODE_ENV set in

Based on your command `NODE_ENV=dev npm run build && npm run watch && npm run tslint` it is not persisted to the enviroment in any way, but will be present when `npm run build` is running.

Comment: Thank for the hint to move setting environmental vars in different script, it helped, see correct answer above.

Answer (score -1):

The right script to set environment variables is in `"serve"`:
This works `"serve": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon dist/Server.js",`.